# Store RGB colors in MySQL. Better as char or int?

Tags: php, mysql, css, rgb

I'm using PHP to query CSS settings from a MySQL database, which is then echoed into a CSS stylesheet. Sample snippet is below:

```
<?php
    $connect = //connect string
    $query = ($connect, "SELECT bgcolor, font FROM displays WHERE name = 'mySettings'");
    while ($row = mysqli_query($query)){
        $bgcolor = $row[bgcolor];
        $font = $row[font];
    }
    echo '
        body {
            background-color: #'.$bgcolor.';
            font: '.$font.';
        }
    ';
?>
```

The table "displays" has one column for each CSS property that's set. Each row represents a set of color/font/padding/margin settings the user has saved.

The column "font" is data type varchar(50). What data type should "bgcolor" be? CSS wants to see a hex value, but there's no hex datatype in MySQL. The logical choice would be to store the value as type int and use the HEX() function in the SELECT statement.

Then again, might it be easier and/or use less space to just store it as a char(6)? PHP is just treating as a string, not an actual number. The hex value won't have any mathematical functions applied to it; it's just pasted into the CSS.

In a case like this, is there any preference between storing the value as an int or a char?

Comment: always store that stuff as a string, not a number.. telephone numbers should normally also be stores as strings, not numbers

Comment: I would just store the CSS attribute value entirely as a string in the database (e.g. "#ab382d"). Without hard-coding the '#' in your CSS, you could even store stuff like "transparent" or "blue" and it will still work in your CSS.

Comment: Your color can have leading 0 so one option is to save as a string and other is to use `hexdec()` and store as a number, but then you have to remember to use function to get the hex by reversing.

Comment: Thanks. Stilly.stack, your comment about phone numbers reminded me of a prof's lesson. He taught us to store phone numbers as strings so that no one can ever attempt a mathematical operation on it. No one will ever need to multiply "555-555-5555" but a programming bug might confuse the "phone" column with the "amount due" column and attempt such an operation. So we make the "phone" column a string, thus ensuring the bug will produce an error rather than bad data. Is the same logic in effect here?

Comment: Dont use int for this. When you want store some data which is actually a number always remember that you save it as an number because you want to calculate something with it. With a phone number or a hex value you dont want to calculate something. So save it as an char.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

Since the values are for display purposes only, I would store the CSS attribute value entirely, whatever it may be, as a string in the database, e.g.:

```
#ab382d
```

This would eliminate the need to have the '#' sitting there in your CSS, so you could then potentially store values such as

- `transparent`
- `blue`
- `rgb(100, 100, 100)`
- (or any other valid `background-color` attribute value)

without needing to know how to render it.

EDIT: You may also want to think about a caching mechanism to reduce the number of hits to the database for stylesheet information that probably doesn't change too often.

Answer (score 5):

24-bit and 32-bit RGB values can be expressed as 32-bit integers, so for efficient storage you can use `int`, but you'll always need to decode it into something human-readable or CSS-readable when loading and saving.

Psuedocode:

```
 UInt32 rgba  = color.R | ( color.G << 8 ) | ( color.B << 16 ) | ( color.A << 24 );
 Color  color = Color.FromRgba( rgba & 0xFF, ( rgba >> 8 ) & 0xFF, ( rgba >> 16 ) & 0xFF, ( rgba >> 24 ) & 0xFF );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

Store red, green and blue in different columns. Each as TINYINT. Since tinyint is between 0..255 (unsigned), not a single bit will be wasted, and you can filter results as you wish(reds, pastels, dark tones etc).