# Storing colours in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, colors, sqldatatypes

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394975/store-rgb-colors-in-mysql-better-as-char-or-int) and the accepted answer advises storing colour values as strings in a database. However, the purpose of storing those values for that question was for display purposes.

I would imagine that using `SUBSTRING()` and `CONV()` to get the values and convert them to integers is slower than bitwise operations (or I can convert to integer on the application end, whether it be PHP or Node, but that still takes time):

```
SELECT CONV(SUBSTRING(colour, 1, 2), 16, 10) AS red,
       CONV(SUBSTRING(colour, 3, 2), 16, 10) AS green,
       CONV(SUBSTRING(colour, 5, 2), 16, 10) AS blue
  FROM table
 WHERE conditions;
```

Compared to:

```
SELECT (colour >> 16) & 0xFF AS red,
       (colour >> 8) & 0xFF AS green,
       colour & 0xFF AS blue
  FROM table
 WHERE conditions;
```

(Those were pseudocode, but you get the idea.)

Would it be appropriate to store them as integers (i.e. 24-bits RGB as `UNSIGNED MEDIUMINT` and 32-bit RGBA as `UNSIGNED INT`)?

Comment: If you have a fixed set of colors and there are not too many, you might want to use a `set` data type.  In general, in SQL databases, optimizations related to bit-fiddling are not worth the effort.  If you need that level of performance, then a database might not be the best solution to your problem.

Comment: The colours are user-supplied values from a colour picker on a web page so it could be any of the 16 million colours

Comment: I would be a little surprised if it made much difference how you stored them. Because of the way human colour perception works, it's really unlikely that you're going to be performing a range query on the stored values (but I may be wrong). Instead , I imagine you would perform some application level calculation on the returned dataset. but id be interested to hear an alternative view

Comment: How do you intend to query such a color table ?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost It would (1) queried by itself when users are viewing/editing the coloured items and (2) joined to another query to retrieve all coloured items belonging to another object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance difference will be small.  In general, operators (>>, &, etc) and function calls (`CONV`, etc) are not as significant as fetching the record.

To that end, if you have a large table (gigabytes), shrinking the datatypes is the most important thing to do.  This will shrink the data, which will decrease the I/O.

`MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` is the tightest possible for RGB -- 3 bytes.  (`BINARY(3)` is also 3 bytes; the code would be something else.)

Your first example seems to store hex in a `CHAR`(6).  That would occupy 6 bytes, or 18 if you had `CHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8`.  `VARCHAR(6)` would be about 8 bytes.  Hence, I don't like the first proffered option.

You could also consider using what MySQL is designed for -- just a data repository.  Then leave the parsing/interpretation, etc, to the application.  That is, write SQL to store and retrieve the "colour" without knowing or caring which bits/bytes refer to Red/etc.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think hex characters even in utf8 are more than one byte. So the color would still only be taking up 6 bytes, since colors aren't made up of any multi byte characters (the same reason that valid ASCII is also valid utf8)

Comment: Hex('京') = 'E4BAAC' -- that's 3 bytes for that one Chinese character.  RGB black and white ('FFFFFF' and '000000') are 3 bytes each.  But, if you say `CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET utf8`, 9 bytes will be allocated (up to 3 bytes per each of 3 characters).  Ascii, cannot receive 'FF'; really `BINARY` is the only proper way to store RGB in 3 bytes.  Storing the string "FFFFFF" (not UNHEX'd) would take 6 bytes.  Well, `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` would also work (3 bytes).

Comment: Allocated, yeah that makes total sense thinking of from that way